# Checking for getActivity() == null on user action

Tags: android

Whenever any of our fragments get an asynchronous response to a network request, we always check whether `getActivity() == null` if we have to touch the activity or use its `Context`.

So our code flow looks something like this:

```
protected void onNetworkResponse(String response) {
   if (getActivity() == null) 
        return;
   getActivity().setProgressBarVisibility(false);
    // Do rest of processing here

}
```

This to us makes sense (please comment if we're doing something wrong! :) ).  However, we also check getActivity() == null on user feedback, like in an onClickListener, if we're going to reference the activity. To me that seems like we're being overly cautious, because by definition if a button on the Fragment was clicked, it had to be attached to an Activity. Are we being overly cautious?

Comment: seems fine to me, it is entirely possible for `getActivity()` to return null so you would throw a NPE

Comment: @tyczj even in an `OnClickListener`? in the `Fragment`?

Comment: you might not need one there but its always better to be safe than sorry

Comment: **IMHO** yes, you're being overcautious. Check getActivity() only makes sense when getting back to the UI Thread (from async tasks).